# Goddess Parvathi hiding the sun

Tags: shiva, parvati, surya

Is there a story where Goddess Parvathi hides the sun when Shiva is talking to her?A friend of mine insists that there is such a story.

Comment: There is a story of closing lord shiva's eyes by goddess parvati which resulted in opening third eye and the sweat of lord shiva creating demon andhaka.
Never heard of this story.

Comment: I dont hear that

Comment: Yes. I'm aware of the Andhaka story, but not this one.